# Modify code to be able to add another value to my dictionary

Tags: python

I need to create a dictionary whose keys are unique course codes and whose values are dictionaries with a single key-value pair describing the sections available for that course code, in alphabetical order, as well as the ID numbers that belong to the specific section, in ascending order.

The data is from a dictionary called student_data that looks like this:

```
student_data[:3]

>>>[{'enlistment': [{'course code': 'UK 60', 'section': 'A'}, 
{'course code': 'GF 24', 'section': 'B'}, 
{'course code': 'ME 40', 'section': 'B'}, 
{'course code': 'VY 44', 'section': 'D'}, 
{'course code': 'EN 94', 'section': 'B'}], 
'id': '201001', 'paid': True, 'school': 'SOSE', 'year level': 2}, 
{'enlistment': [{'course code': 'EQ 61', 'section': 'D'}, 
{'course code': 'UZ 22', 'section': 'B'}, 
{'course code': 'KS 36', 'section': 'B'}, 
{'course code': 'VH 63', 'section': 'A'}, 
{'course code': 'IW 81', 'section': 'C'}], 
'id': '211002', 'paid': True, 'school': 'JGSOM', 'year level': 1}, 
{'enlistment': [{'course code': 'WE 15', 'section': 'D'}, 
{'course code': 'ZP 68', 'section': 'A'}, 
{'course code': 'GI 78', 'section': 'A'}, 
{'course code': 'GK 72', 'section': 'C'}, 
{'course code': 'FA 24', 'section': 'D'}, 
{'course code': 'UJ 28', 'section': 'A'}], 
'id': '201003', 'paid': True, 'school': 'JGSOM', 'year level': 2}]
```

Format of the desired output:

```
{
    course_code: [{
        "section": section_letter,
        "class list": [
           id_number_1,
           id_number_2,
           id_number_3,
        ]
    }
    course_code: [{
        "section": section_letter,
        "class list": [
           id_number_1,
           id_number_2,
           id_number_3,
        ]
    }
]
}
```

My code at the moment looks like this but this only takes the sections for each course code. I need to take the ID numbers under each section of each course code as well. Does anyone know how to do this by modifying my code below?

```
courses = {}

for i in student_data:
    for j in i['enlistment']:
        if j['course code'] not in courses:
            courses[j['course code']] = {'sections':[j['section']]}
        else:
            if j['section'] not in courses[j['course code']]['sections']:
                courses[j['course code']]['sections'].append(j['section']) 

for i in courses.keys():
    courses[i]['sections'] = sorted(courses[i]['sections'])
```

Please help

Answer (score -1):

This will do what you want.  Your proposed output format is not really very useful; instead of a list of objects, each course should have a dictionary with the section ID as the key and the class list as the value.  That's actually what I construct first, and then transform it:

```
student_data = [
{'enlistment': [{'course code': 'UK 60', 'section': 'A'},
{'course code': 'GF 24', 'section': 'B'},
{'course code': 'ME 40', 'section': 'B'},
{'course code': 'VY 44', 'section': 'D'},
{'course code': 'EN 94', 'section': 'B'}],
'id': '201001', 'paid': True, 'school': 'SOSE', 'year level': 2},
{'enlistment': [{'course code': 'EQ 61', 'section': 'D'},
{'course code': 'UZ 22', 'section': 'B'},
{'course code': 'KS 36', 'section': 'B'},
{'course code': 'VH 63', 'section': 'A'},
{'course code': 'IW 81', 'section': 'C'}],
'id': '211002', 'paid': True, 'school': 'JGSOM', 'year level': 1},
{'enlistment': [{'course code': 'WE 15', 'section': 'D'},
{'course code': 'ZP 68', 'section': 'A'},
{'course code': 'GI 78', 'section': 'A'},
{'course code': 'GK 72', 'section': 'C'},
{'course code': 'FA 24', 'section': 'D'},
{'course code': 'UJ 28', 'section': 'A'}],
'id': '201003', 'paid': True, 'school': 'JGSOM', 'year level': 2}]

courses = {}

for i in student_data:
    for j in i['enlistment']:
        if j['course code'] not in courses:
            courses[j['course code']] = {}
        if j['section'] not in courses[j['course code']]:
            courses[j['course code']][j['section']] = []
        courses[j['course code']][j['section']].append( i['id'] )

from pprint import pprint

for cc,it in courses.items():
    courses[cc] = list( { 'section': k, 'class_list': v } for k,v in it.items() )

pprint(courses)
```

Output:

```
{'EN 94': [{'class_list': ['201001'], 'section': 'B'}],
 'EQ 61': [{'class_list': ['211002'], 'section': 'D'}],
 'FA 24': [{'class_list': ['201003'], 'section': 'D'}],
 'GF 24': [{'class_list': ['201001'], 'section': 'B'}],
 'GI 78': [{'class_list': ['201003'], 'section': 'A'}],
 'GK 72': [{'class_list': ['201003'], 'section': 'C'}],
 'IW 81': [{'class_list': ['211002'], 'section': 'C'}],
 'KS 36': [{'class_list': ['211002'], 'section': 'B'}],
 'ME 40': [{'class_list': ['201001'], 'section': 'B'}],
 'UJ 28': [{'class_list': ['201003'], 'section': 'A'}],
 'UK 60': [{'class_list': ['201001'], 'section': 'A'}],
 'UZ 22': [{'class_list': ['211002'], 'section': 'B'}],
 'VH 63': [{'class_list': ['211002'], 'section': 'A'}],
 'VY 44': [{'class_list': ['201001'], 'section': 'D'}],
 'WE 15': [{'class_list': ['201003'], 'section': 'D'}],
 'ZP 68': [{'class_list': ['201003'], 'section': 'A'}]}
```